# Convert selected dataframe columns to factor using loop?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df`. It contains factors for the most part, besides select numeric columns.

I want to create a data quality report and everything is being read in as integers. So I captured the following column indexes and wanted to convert those columns to type factor:

```
n_cols = c(1,3,4,9:17,28:35)

for (x in length(df)) {
  if (x %in% n_cols == FALSE) {
    df[,x] = as.factor(df[,x])
  }
}
```

The code is running, but it is not properly converted when I call `str(df)`.

I come from a Python background, so some of this syntax is newer to me.

Comment: which columns do you want to change to factor? The ones in `n_cols` or the ones not listed in `n_col`??

Comment: Your problem is in your for loop set up `for (x in length(df))`. This only checks the last column. You should do something like `for (x in 1:length(df))` or `for (x in seq_along(df))`.

Comment: No need of any loops `df[n_cols] <- lapply(df[n_cols], as.factor)`

Comment: @RonakShah, since OP has `if (x %in% n_cols == FALSE)` shouldn't your example be the complement of `n_cols`? Something like : `df[!(1:length(df) %in% n_cols)]`

Comment: @JosephWood yes, most probably. But if that is the case I would suggest OP to have `n_cols` of columns to turn into factors instead which would make it simpler. Or they can use `setdiff` to get them. Also, `I captured the following column indexes and wanted to convert those columns to type factor` is confusing.

Comment: I wouldn't call it `n_cols`, it's not a number, it's a vector of indices of factor columns, so I'd call it `factorCols` or `factorColIdxs`.

Comment: I show how you can do it in a one-liner with `lapply`. Often in R the answer to "Do I need a loop to do X?" is No, you can vectorize it.

Comment: @JosephWood just do `df[-n_cols]`

Comment: @RonakShah , I agree with you. Also, I missed the most obvious way of getting the compliment as was pointed out by Onyambu.

Comment: @Onyambu you are 100% correct. Somehow, that did not enter my thought process last night. I use that all of the time too :D.

Comment: @JosephWood Can't believe that I missed the "1:" before the length, thank you!

Comment: You got two working answers; feel free to upvote any you found useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert selected columns in a data frame to factors **inside a for-loop** I have created a reproducible example below using the `mtcars` dataset.

Note: This depends on specifying a vector of column numbers that you **do** want coerced to factors.  If you want to invert this logic you can insert a `!` inside the if() statement to negate the logic.

```r
# example data
data(mtcars)

# columns to go to factors
to_fact <- c(1, 3, 5, 7)

for(x in seq_along(mtcars)) {
  if(x %in% to_fact){
    mtcars[,x] <- as.factor(mtcars[,x]) 
  }
}

str(mtcars)
#> 'data.frame':    32 obs. of  11 variables:
#>  $ mpg : Factor w/ 25 levels "10.4","13.3",..: 16 16 19 17 13 12 3 20 19 14 ...
#>  $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>  $ disp: Factor w/ 27 levels "71.1","75.7",..: 13 13 6 16 23 15 23 12 10 14 ...
#>  $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>  $ drat: Factor w/ 22 levels "2.76","2.93",..: 16 16 15 5 6 1 7 11 17 17 ...
#>  $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>  $ qsec: Factor w/ 30 levels "14.5","14.6",..: 6 10 22 24 10 29 5 27 30 19 ...
#>  $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>  $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

Created on 2018-08-31 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

In order to complete this more succinctly you can also use the `purrr` package for functional programming:

```r
mtcars[to_fact] <- purrr::map_df(mtcars[to_fact], as.factor)
```

Comment: `for(x in seq_along(mtcars)) { ... if(x %in% to_fact){` is totally unnecessary, Just directly do `for (factorCol in to_fact) {` ... already!

Comment: Yeah I agree, just trying to mirror the OP syntax they were having trouble with. Questionable to even use a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can do it in a one-liner with `sapply/lapply`:

```
mtcars[,factorCols] <- lapply(mtcars[,factorCols], as.factor)
```

2) Longer alternative: no need for the nested `for-if`; you know the specific column-indices of the columns you want to convert. So directly iterate over them, already:

```
data(mtcars)
factorCols <- c(1,3,5,7)

for (factorCol in factorCols) {
  mtcars[, factorCol] <- as.factor(mtcars[, factorCol])
}
```

which is essentially a one-liner.

Comment: Why not just `mtcars[factorCols] <- lapply(mtcars[factorCols], as.factor)` and do away with the anonymous function? Not entirely sure, but I think it will also avoid needing to run `[` `length(factorCols)` times instead of just once.

Comment: @thelatemail: thanks, that's simpler, I used your version. I thought it lumped all the column levels together as `as.factor(mtcars[,factorCols])` does which gives garbage